# Passing params to a simpleforms f.association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have many equipments that belongs to an Office

From the list of Offices, I put this link to pass the id to the form of a new equipment
`<%= link_to "", new_equipment_path(office: params[:id])" %>`

The generated url appears to be ok, passes the correct id of the clicked office
`/equipments/new?office=6`

And I check with an open cell like this and I see the number id (6 for example)
`<%= f.input :observations, input_html: { value: params[:office]} %>`

The problem is when I try with the real cell that is f.association, is just in blank, manually I can pick a number (1,2,3,4,5,6, etc) but It's not putting the number that I pass in the params, I try as hidden and other options and no luck
`<%= f.association :office, label_method: :id, value_method: :id, input_html: { value: params[:office] } %>`

#show.html.erb (offices)

```
<% @offices.each do |office| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= office.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Add new equipment", new_equipment_path(office:params[:id])%></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

## form.html.erb (new equipment)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@equipment) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :office, label_method: :id, value_method: :id, input_html: { value: params[:office] } %>
    <%= f.input :observations, input_html: { value: params[:office]}%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please add more of the relevant code. Your description is vague and leaves people to have to guess. Post the relevant parts of the form. Also what is the console saying when you post the form???

Comment: What is the actual model code? Does `Office` accept attributes for `Equipment`?  Does your Office controller allow the equipment ids in the params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I try without simpleforms and work without a problem

```
<%= form.hidden_field :office_id, value: params['office'] %>
```

The problem was that simpleforms does not take input_html: { value: params[:office] in f.association, I change for this and it work

```
<%= f.input :office_id, value_method: :id, label_method: :id, input_html: { value: params[:office] }, as: :hidden %>
```